# Flink TaskManager MetaSpace OOM

Tags: memory-leaks, apache-flink, taskmanager

I am using Flink JDBCInputFormat and after repeated execution of my job, I see Flink TaskManager JVM MetaSpace keep on increasing and at one point TaskManager goes down due to OOM. The job is very simple, just read 2 rows from database and print it. What would cause this leak?